# Netbeans not preserving ACL permissions

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

We are currently running our ubuntu server with ACLs for file permission.

And I'm using netbeans as the IDE. However, first, I did not turn on the "Preserve Permission" functionality on Netbeans, and it screwed up. All files permissions are changed to 644 which should be 770.  Then After I turned it on. It seems only copy UGO rights over, instead of ACLs the server is running. And this blocked the access of apache user "www-data".

I'm just wondering, without touching anything on the server, How do I configure Netbeans properly.

TYIA

Answer (score 0):

`chmod -R`

can fix it for you. Or

`find * -type f -exec chmod 770 {} ];`

I am not sure what you mean by 'preserve permission' functionality in NetBeans. If you really think it is a bug and describe it better you should file it into their bug tracker - https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Comment: Preserve Remote File Permission (Permission are not preserved for local files,only for remote ones).